How do Indo-European languages deal with the grammatical gender of personal names?
How do Indo-European languages deal with the grammatical gender of personal names?
The reason I'm asking this question is because there's a female character named Rio Morales from the Spider-Verse movies. Rio/río, as a common noun in Portuguese and Spanish, is grammtically masculine. I'm not sure if it's used as an actual girl's name in Portuguese/Spanish-speaking regions, but since this is the name of a character in two very popular movies, I'm assuming non-English writers have to address the gender of her name at some point. I'm most familiar with French, and from what I can tell based on this one French quote, it seems the grammatical gender of the name may be linked to the social gender of the person:

sa mère Rio Morales était vivante

Here, vivante is feminine, although it might be agreeing with sa mère ("his mother") instead of Rio Morales.
Then there's a quote from Sony's website for the Spider-Man video games:

mais la conseillère municipale Rio Morales est surtout connue pour son engagement inébranlable

Connue is feminine, but in this case, there's still some ambiguity as to whether it agrees with the name, or with the feminine phrase la conseillère municipale ("the city councilwoman").
Another quote from a wiki which seems to treats the name as masculine.

Rio Morales est devenu le conseil municipal de New York

Here, devenu is masculine. I'm not quite sure if this phrase makes much sense, though, because conseil means "council", not "councillor".
So how does gender-based Indo-European languages deal with personal names (especially unisex names)? Let's say there's a construction that directly requires gender agreement, something like this:

Rio is beautiful

where the adjective for "beautiful" must agree with the name Rio, which we know is of a woman, and you cannot wriggle your way out of this by moving on to another sentence, with a feminine noun phrase ("this lady is beautiful") or pronoun ("she is beautiful").

That French wiki page reads rather unnaturally to me – it’s quite possible it’s a machine translation, in which case it would have no way to know that Rio is female. In general, the grammatical gender of a person’s name matches their social gender. Your final example isn’t very well-chosen, though, because bilingue is the same in the masculine and feminine, so regardless of gender, it would be ‘Rio est bilingue’. If you were to say it in Icelandic, though, it would be just as you’d expect: Río er tvítyngdur if Rio is male Rio, but Río er tvítyngd if Rio is female.

Good point about "bilingual". I checked translations into Romance languages and it does seem their equivalents of "bilingual" are gender-invariable.

With your updated example, it’s completely clear and unambiguous: Rio est beau means Rio is a man; Rio est belle means Rio is a woman. In theory, of course, you could be using Rio as a word-as-word, saying that it’s a beautiful name. In this case, it would be masculine (because un nom is masculine), but I think that would be more likely to be phrased with a neuter subject as C’est beau, ‘Rio’ or ‘Rio’, c’est beau ça.

In Latin and Ancient Greek, there are two patterns seen when the form of a name suggests the wrong gender for the person it refers to.
For many names, especially native ones (but some foreign ones too), they'll be modified to read as the appropriate gender. The daughter of Valerius will be named Valeria, since -a is the most common ending for (grammatically) feminine nouns. This is how we've ended up with Moses and Solomon in English, even though the Hebrew doesn't have final consonants there—η (ē) and ω (ō) in Greek are feminine endings, with ης (ēs) and ων (ōn) as their masculine equivalents.
Other names, especially foreign ones (but some native ones too), will keep their original form, but change their grammatical gender to match the person they're referring to. "Sulla" looks feminine, and is indeed grammatically feminine when it refers to a woman, but is grammatically masculine when it refers to the famous dictator.
Which pattern is followed depends on the name more than the person. Julius Caesar's mother was named Aurelia Cotta; her father was named Aurelius Cotta.

Do you know how it works in modern Greek? It doesn't seem as though you can modify names as easily as in ancient Greek, where foreign names were rendered more fluidly. I looked up Greek Wikipedia articles for Barack Obama, Joe Biden and Kamala Harris and they all seem to be pure, faithful transcriptions. It's the same case for Icelandic, one of the most conservative languages where native names must be declinable per Icelandic grammar, and even mandated by the government to match children's gender assigned at birth.

@Vun-HughVaw I'm afraid I know very little about Modern Greek. Ancient languages are my area of focus.

@Vun-HughVaw Even In Icelandic, modern foreign names are either indeclinable (e.g., Barack Obama or Joe Biden in all cases) or declined as though they were Icelandic according to the person’s gender and what declension the name most resembles (e.g., genitives like Baracks Obama, Joes Bidens, Rihönnu, Angelu Merkel or Kamölu Harris). But there are no set rules; sometimes both coexist even for the same person, and I’ve seen people say that, for example, til Merkelar ‘to Merkel’ sounds fine, but til Angelu Merkelar sounds weird. But to the extent they’re declined, gender matches the person.

In many languages, there is a pervasive pattern where proper names of female persons trigger feminine grammatical agreement and proper names of male persons trigger masculine grammatical agreement, regardless of whether the form or etymological origin of the name would suggest a different gender. As far as I know, this is the case in modern French and Spanish. (In the case of names that contain an article as an inherent part of the name, like French Le Pen, I don't consider the article to count as an example of synchronic gender agreement, since it isn't an external word.)
Apart from the examples discussed in Draconis's answer (masculine names that look like they have the form of feminine nouns), there are examples in Greek and Latin of names that have the form of neuter nouns but take feminine agreement, such as ἡ Δόρκιον, haec Dorcium.
Use of neuter article in German for female names with a diminutive suffix
It seems that in German an article placed before a name with the diminutive suffix -chen (which regularly produces a neuter noun in the case of common nouns) may show agreement with the name's neuter form rather than with its semantic referent. When I asked modern German speakers whether they would accept using the feminine article before the name Gretchen in a phrase like das/die arme Gretchen, "the poor Gretchen", the consensus of the replies was that the neuter article das must be used (although the feminine would be usual for a co-referential pronoun) in accordance with the rule that diminutives in -chen are neuter. This is a fairly marginal case, since in Standard German personal names are not usually used with a definite article. Here's a Reddit thread in German that provides some additional discussion: die Gretchen oder das Gretchen?
In a comment on the question "Languages with masculine nouns for various female entities", or feminine nouns for male entities, JanusBahsJacquet mentioned a rule that Irish diminutive -ín produces masculine nouns (such as cailín (m) ‘girl’). I don't know any Irish, and based on what I gathered from online resources, this rule may not be consistently applied in all Irish dialects (e.g. see 1, 2, 3), and even in cases where the word is masculine it seems it is used with a feminine referential pronoun. Overall, I'm not sure whether female names ending in -ín such as Máirín, Meidhbhín, Réiltín are masculine in any variety of Irish, but that could be something to look into.
Use of neuter agreement in German and Polish dialects for women or certain subcategories of women
There are some European language varieties where certain categories of female persons are regularly referred to with the neuter, e.g. some Southern Polish dialects are said to use neuter or masculine agreement for unmarried or young women. It sounds like in these languages, the same name, in reference to the same woman, might take different gender agreement depending on her age or marital status.
This map, posted by Sir Cornflakes in a comment on the question "Proper names: does grammatical gender imply natural gender?", shows that there are also regions of Germany where any woman's name (whether ending in a diminutive suffix or not) is used with a neuter article, such as das/dat Anna.
It seems it is hypothesized that that pattern may have originated by extension from use of the neuter with diminutive names. Here are some other articles I cound find on it:

Das Anna und ihr Hund. Weibliche Hundenamen im Neutrum?
Der onymische Artikel im Schweizerdeutschen in seiner Funktion als Genusmarker
Neutering endearment


To answer your question, yes, in the South we basically productively use diminutive suffixes on names.

-chen and -lein and their cognates are not the only diminutive suffixes, there is also -i and its gender varies.

In the South or in dialects it can be normal to refer to girls and women neuter even without making the name diminutive (still usually with a short form but not necessarily with -le / -li).

“This is a fairly marginal case, since in Standard German personal names are not usually used with a definite article” — Except of course in the same context where names are used with definite articles in English, namely when they’re modified: ‘the lovely Gretchen’, ‘the fair Helen’, etc.

In Dutch only the neuter demonstrative "dat" -- rather than the fem/masc "die" -- is grammatical before a diminutive female or male name: "dat slimme Grietje ("that smart Grietje"), "dat domme Hansje" ("that stupid Hansje") versus "die slimme Griet", "die slimme Hans". (In colloquial speech "die arme Grietje" might also be actually used, but never "dat arme Griet".)

The German diminutive thing also works for male names. Though maybe not as strongly? Consider this version of Hänschen klein, which has both "er hat frohem Mut" (masculine) and "kein Hänschen mehr* (neuter)

Despite grammatical gender in German grammar, there is no overt marking of female names unless it is a feminine variant of a masculine name, e.g. *m. Heiko vs. f. Heike, Francophone m. Henry vs. f. Henriette. There is no notable grammatical agreement in the inflection, e.g. possesive m. sein vs. ihr "their" (his or her), and none in the verb 3.sg geht "goes". Consequently, names like m. André, Andreas vs. f. Andrea which are common in German but may be confused  in Italian Andrea(s) don't serve for confusion much. Retrieval could take a bit longer. Its root *Hnér- "man" is slightly ambiguous in translation and it suggests that names were chosen to agree with gender, e.g. f. die Rose, but the fact is that most names löhave lost their etymological connotation in practice a llng tine ago.
You might equally question if @Draconis, @brass_tacks and @vectory are gendered. On my part I can say that Y is a mathematical variable (vec.y in object oriented languages) but untyped (as to its unit, I'm the 1), and that /i/ serves for diminuation, which would be grammatically neuter, as well as to adjectivalize, which would be masculine. Instead of vector'ish I might prefer vectoriks as a pun, but I feel like that wasn't the question.
You know, a joke that has to be explained loses its funny. So the question is bound for a non-answer.

Do you realize the conditions I impose, whether you personally object to them or not, are there for a reason? The point isn't about whether "he/his" agrees with "Andrew" and "she/her" agrees with "Andrea". Unless Andrew and Andrea are categorically masculine and feminine as grammatical nouns per se, without social considerations, what's the point of this non-answer of yours? In English where neither grammatical gender nor gender-wise grammatical agreement exists, we use "he/him" and "she/her" exactly like that.

I believe whst I said is you phrased your question poorly. That comment had been removed. I also am saying "Retrieval could take a bit longer." and you seem to be asking for an easier way but there is none. With respect to the specific question on a fictional character you might want to see World Building SE. It's clearly off topic here. The other answers don't appear to respond to the question but name some mildly interesting facts, to boot, too.

It's not that my text is gibberish, it's just incomprehensible to you why anyone would be unsupportive of your highly pressumptious question. Draconis didn't answer anything, it just restated the most obvious context of your question, Spanish being a Romance language. Asteroids aka Brass Tacks misrepresents the context of regional German "das", because not everything that looks like neuter is necessarily so.
